# php contact form working but not displaying dialogue box with success message on submit

Tags: php, forms

I am using identical php code for my contact forms on two different websites. The contact forms are working as they should for both sites (posting to the specified email address) with exception of the dialogue box that is supposed to be displayed with the success message is not displaying on one of the sites.

I have included (2) two screenshots; 1 that shows the dialogue box as it should be displayed

[image: the result I want]
and the other is a blank webpage that is displayed with a "result":200 message

[image: result I don't want]

Below is the HTML for the site that is not displaying the dialogue box:

```
<form action="contact.php" id="contact-form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" class="theme-form">
    <div class="form-row row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mt-10" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mt-10" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mt-10" name="custom_fon_number" id="custom_fon_number" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mt-10" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="form-control mt-10" name="custom_comment" id="custom_comment" placeholder="Write your message" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- List token -->
        <!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
        <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="ymyfS" />
        <!-- Add subscriber to the follow-up sequence with a specified day (optional) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />
        <!-- Subscriber button -->
        <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-solid" type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is the PHP code I am using for the both sites:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    try {

        if (isset($_POST['conf_email']) and !empty($_POST['conf_email'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid field.');
        }

        $requiredParams = ['first_name','email','custom_comment'];

        foreach ($requiredParams as $requiredParam) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$requiredParam]) or (isset($_POST[$requiredParam]) and empty($_POST[$requiredParam]))) {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid field.');
            }
        }

        $to = 'mail@middlemaan.com';
        $from = trim($_POST['email']);
        $subject = 'Sedona Precious Metals Contact Form';

        $messageHtml = sprintf('<p>Sedona Precious Metals Contact Form</p>
<p>First Name: %s</p>
<p>Last Name: %s</p>
<p>Phone: %s</p>
<p>Email: %s</p>
<p>Comment: %s</p>
', $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['custom_fon_number'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['custom_comment']);

        $postArray = array('from'    => $from,
                           'to'      => $to,
                           'subject' => $subject,
                           'html'    => $messageHtml,
                           'text'    => strip_tags($messageHtml));

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:key-aba0e6ca4e9ad581fb557680ad93bfa2');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/mg.hemptrimpro.com/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray);

        $j = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo json_encode(['result'=>500, 'message'=>$ex->getMessage()]);
        die;
    }
    echo json_encode(['result'=>200]);
```

JS Code identical on both sites

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
        
        //get input field values
        var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
        
        //simple validation at client's end
        //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
        var proceed = true;
        if (user_name == "") {
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if (user_email == "") {
            $('input[name=email]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        
        if (user_message == "") {
            $('textarea[name=message]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
            proceed = false;
        }
        
        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if (proceed) {
            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'userName': user_name,
                'userEmail': user_email,
                'userMessage': user_message
            };
            
            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){
            
                //load json data from server and output message     
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
                }
                else {
                
                    output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                    
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val('');
                    $('#contact_form textarea').val('');
                }
                
                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
            
        }
        
        return false;
    });
    
    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").keyup(function(){
        $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").css('border-color', '');
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
    
});
```

Comment: i have no idea why the HTML is missing and the PHP is formatted this way... this is NOT what I posted

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: FYI, you don't need to test `isset()` before `!empty()`.

Comment: `contact.php` returns JSON. That's what you see when you submit the form.

Comment: What did you expect `echo json_encode(['result'=>200]);` to look like?

Comment: Scripts that return JSON are usually used with AJAX, not for normal form submission.

Comment: If you want the result to be displayed in a dialogue box, you need to use JavaScript to submit the form data with AJAX.

Comment: Here is the JS; please see above. Please keep in mind I am using the exact same code on two websites and it works "as is" on one site but not the other.

Comment: Why do you keep posting unformatted code? Didn't you see how I fixed the formatting of your original code, so you could copy that?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console on the site that doesn't work? I suspect it's getting an error so the `return false` in the JS isn't executed, and your form is getting submitted normally.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using jQuery ( or vanilla javascript) to make an ajax call to a page. Let's call it `process.php`.

I haven't tested the following code, but I think that should work.
This could be a good starting point for further customization.

Note: This code uses jQuery to perform the ajax request for saving time. If you prefer you can use any other library or the native fetch API.
Remember to include the jQuery cdn or minified file with the latest version.

For example, you can have something like this for the front end:

```html
<!--html code ...-->

<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<!--html code ...-->


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"), // Get the form's action attribute
            method: $(this).attr("method"), // Get the form's method attribute
            data: $(this).serialize(), // Serialize the form data
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    alert("Success! Status 200 received.");
                } else {
                    alert("Something went wrong.");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The PHP page could be something like this:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    
    // Now you can work with the $name variable or other data sent from the form

    $response = array("status" => 200, "message" => "Form data processed successfully");
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Handle the case where the request is not of POST type
    http_response_code(400); // Bad Request
    echo "Bad Request";
}
?>
```